# What does "edit removed during grace period" mean?

Tags: support, editing

This [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/266612/what-does-the-phrase-scornful-pity-mean) is showing an edit done almost an hour later. However when I clicked on the revision history, I got this:

[image: edit removed message]

What does this line mean? Rather, I want to know when it is shown? Also, what is the grace period?

Comment: Have a look at [this Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133301/undone-edits-disappear-from-revision-history)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grace period (for edits) is a 5-minute window, in which all edits will be 'collapsed' into a single edit. You can hit the submit button as often as you want, it will still be just one edit. For details, see [this tag wiki on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/grace-period/info).

When somebody edits an *existing* post, that will create a new revision. If they decide within those 5 minutes to rollback all their changes, there are effectively no changes, but the revision is not deleted. Instead, you'll see this message [Edit removed during grace period]. For the reasons why this is so, see the Meta Stack Exchange post @Void found: [Undone edits disappear from revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133301/295232)